# How to make Transition animation run on other thread not on the main thread

Tags: ios

I'm trying to do a transition animation from UIImage background color to an actual image loaded from server. I found that the transition make the UITableView stutter while the animation is happening. Is there a way to make the transition smooth without causing the stutter.

```
float fadeDuration = 1.0f;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor averageColor];
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                [UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                                  duration:fadeDuration
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                animations:^{
                                    imageView.image = toImage;
                                } completion:nil];
```

Comment: just try and reply if that worked for you ?

Comment: are you performing above code in some kind of callback or async thread?

Comment: @luk2302 I'm actually call it from [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) I'm using Parse here.

Comment: @Geeroz I posted a fix for you in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you first call `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` the code you write in that block is not executed on the main thread but one some other thread. But **UI changes have to be performed on the UI / main thread**.

To get the code to be exectued on the main thread you have to wrap the `UIView transitionWithView` call into an `dispatch_asnyc`:

```
// ... some non-UI code
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                      duration:fadeDuration
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        imageView.image = toImage;
                    } completion:nil
    ];
    // ... more UI code
});
// ... more non-UI code
```

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks @luk2302